# Adding an external directory to Compass watch list. Sass

Tags: css, sass, config, compass

I'm importing another SCSS file from a folder outside of the folder thats being watched by compass. How can I edit my config.rb to watch for changes in that external folder as well as the one currently being watched?

My folder structure

themes/mytheme/sass_files - currently being watched

themes/othertheme/sass_files - I want to also watch this folder for changes.

My config file is located in /themes/mytheme

My config.rb

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "/"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true
```

Could I edit this document to track the other folder, or do I have to move the .rb file?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you expecting the CSS files generated from your other directory to go?